# node require module passing arg with square brackets? is this a mistake?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I saw the following nodeJS code on a git hub repo:

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
, config = require('./config/config')[env]
, auth = require('./config/middlewares/authorization')
, mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

I've never seen the square brackets before `[env]`  is this a mistake?
I thought args could only be passed in normal brackets `( )`. I could not find documentation anywhere about this.

repo in question is here https://github.com/diki/nodejs-passport-boilerplate and its on line 17 of `server.js`.

Comment: The `require('./config/config')` will be a plain JSON, and you can access it's properties using `dot` notation or with square brackets `['myProp']`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at their [`config.js`](https://github.com/diki/nodejs-passport-boilerplate/blob/master/config/config.example.js) example, that file exports an object with each environment as keys:

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    db: 'mongodb://localhost/noobjs_dev',
    root: rootPath,
    // ...
  },
  test: {
    db: 'mongodb://localhost/noobjs_test',
    root: rootPath,
    // ...
  },
  production: {}
}
```

The square brackets will select only the configs related to the environment defined in your `NODE_ENV` variable.

Assuming `NODE_ENV` holds the value `development`, this would be the same as doing this:

```
var config = require('./config/config').development;
```

Which is the same as this:

```
var config = require('./config/config')['development'];
```

The advantage of square brackets it that they allow you to select the key on the object dynamically.

Comment: so the square brackets are not being passed in at all (even though they resemble the passing of arguments) and are square bracket notation to access the objects properties. 
Thanks for pointing this out !